# Bicycle rental near Kastrup Airport, Denmark?

Tags: bicycles, denmark, copenhagen, cph

I plant to bicycle from Kastrup Airport (CPH) into Copenhagen itself. Does anyone know of a bicycle rental near to the airport?

Comment: Maybe usefull: Copehagen has a free public bike system in the city. I am not sure how far it goes outside the city. Maybe there is something like it near the airport

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Googla Maps, there is a bicycle rental shop little bit far from the airport, the address is:

> Bikify
>   Holmbladsgade 27
>   2300 København
>   Denmark

The distance is around 6km, you can take the bus that will drop you there faster, or you can walk and make it in 1hr. This is the full route in [Google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!data=!4m23!3m22!1m5!1sCopenhagen+Airport%2C+Lufthavnsboulevarden+6%2C+2770+Kastrup%2C+Denmark!2s0x4653ab102787956b%3A0xfc95bcff205ab30b!3m2!3d55.629563!4d12.639255!1m5!1sBikify%2C+Holmbladsgade+27%2C+2300+K%C3%B8benhavn%2C+Denmark!2s0x4652534a2780068d%3A0xfc3b8c195b564789!3m2!3d55.665123!4d12.606204!2e2!3m8!1m3!1d43714!2d12.6255686!3d55.6476527!3m2!1i1920!2i932!4f13.1&fid=0).

[image: bicycle rental]
*Screenshot from Google Maps*

Anyway, there is a much closer shop, not sure if it rents or not. You can pass by it on the way and check it, it is only 1 km from the airport, here is the route in [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!data=!4m23!3m22!1m5!1sCopenhagen+Airport%2C+Lufthavnsboulevarden+6%2C+2770+Kastrup%2C+Denmark!2s0x4653ab102787956b%3A0xfc95bcff205ab30b!3m2!3d55.629563!4d12.639255!1m5!1sViking+City+Cykler%2C+Kastrupkrogen+2%2C+2770+Kastrup%2C+Denmark!2s0x4653ab615e212dfb%3A0x4909f61d0f4e1a90!3m2!3d55.636464!4d12.642391!2e2!3m8!1m3!1d10933!2d12.64922!3d55.6329009!3m2!1i1920!2i932!4f13.1&fid=0), and the address is:

> Viking City Cykler
>   Kastrupkrogen 2
>   2770 Kastrup
>   Denmark